# How to generate a 2d grid (X,Y) with a Z value using numpy or pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

As the title states I want to generate a 2d grid. Essentially X, Y coordinates with a Z value. I want this grid to go from X: -175:175 Y: -175:175 and fill in all Z values with 0. I also already have some X,Y, and Z values in a df that I've created like:

```
+-----+-----+--------+
|  X  |  Y  |   Z    |
+-----+-----+--------+
| -45 |   3 |   -.03 |
|  10 |   4 |    .06 |
|  20 | -97 | -.0345 |
+-----+-----+--------+
```

Then I create a very basic grid with:

```
grid = np.zeros((350, 350))
```

Now I want to create a df (or np array) that will go from -175 to 175 (both X in Y) and fill those values with my df and if they don't exist in my df just fill them with 0.

The ultimate goal is to graph those x,y,z points (Maybe in a heat map or something not sure yet) if that helps give some context.

All help is appreciated and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `pivot`:

```
(df.pivot(index='X', columns='Y', values='Z')9
   .reindex(np.arange(-175,175))
   .reindex(np.arange(-175,175), axis=1)
   .fillna(0)
)
```

Comment: silly question, but why do I need to do this pivot stuff?

Comment: You don’t have to. It’s just one option. You can, for example, do a double loop and update your `grid`, but that’ll be slower.

Comment: okay I'm getting some issues. I get an error that says "Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape". This makes sense, since in my df I could have something like X: -10 Y:-7 Z: 5, X: -10 Y:-3 Z:3. And according to the code the index col should be X which can have duplicate values, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: No, it's more like you have duplicate pair `X,Y`. What do you want to do in this case?

Comment: you were right, I was using a df before I dropped duplicates. Thanks!

Comment: Also last question, what does this return? do I just set my df to what you just put, or is this done in place?

Comment: It returns a new dataFrame. (Re)Assign it to something.

Comment: Thank you for all the help. It's working as intended!

Comment: Hey last question, so I used the code posted above and then did something simple like:sns.heatmap(df_grid), but when it displays it they Y is on the x axis and the X is on the Y axis. Do you might know why?

Comment: That's how `sns` works. Either swap `X,Y` in `df.pivot()` or do `sns.heatmap(df_grid.T)`.

Comment: much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to plot x,y,z (as value) use: contourf from matplotlib (https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/contourf_demo.html#contourf-demo)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33813081)